# What's a reliable command-line Linux app for SFTP uploading?

Tags: linux, centos, ftp, scp, sftp

I have to upload a large number of files via SFTP.

I need a command-line app to do this on Linux CentOS 6.

Yes, I've searched on Google and haven't found any that are reliable. I tried to use scp and sftp but some of the files were corrupted during transfer. I need one that's reliable and is going to ensure that the files are not corrupt.

Any recommendations?

Thanks!

Comment: I would probably use `rsync`, e. g. like [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-copy-files-with-rsync-over-ssh).

Comment: I've never seen `scp` or `sftp` corrupting files. The transfer goes over SSH which itself has integrity checking. So the only time the contents can get corrupted without `scp`/`sftp` noticing is reading/writing files to/from file system. And if your file systems are broken, nothing can save you. My guess is that your files are being written to, while you are transferring them.